# How to extract specific numbers amounts from a string and add them using postgres

Tags: postgresql

```
7 years/100,000 miles. xyz $1200 abc 451.00| hhh 14.00
```

How can I get output=1665 in postgresql. I want to add numbers that follow **$** sign or  numbers that have a **decimal** point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with data(str) as (
values ('7 years/100,000 miles. xyz $1200 abc 451.00| hhh 14.00 ')
)

select sum(item::numeric)
from (
    select unnest(regexp_matches(str, '(\d+\.\d+)|\$(\d+)', 'g')) as item
    from data
    ) s

   sum   
---------
 1665.00
(1 row)
```

See [regex explanation.](https://regex101.com/r/iAF9qp/1)

Read about  [POSIX Regular Expressions.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)